# Groovy GString variable double substitution

Tags: java, templates, groovy, gstring

I have a Groovy Script. In Java via a Binding I provide:

```
binding.put( 'a','Hello')
```

I run the script via GroovyShell and I do :

```
print "${a}"
```

will print

```
Hello
```

I need to `print "${a}"` where `a` can be any text as result of calling another method.
Just print a variable whose name is determined at runtime. How is this possible ?

One more example to clarify:

```
binding.put( 'm','n')
binding.put( 'n','p')
```

print ???? and the output should be `'p'`, where `'m'` is known in script but not `'n'`

Comment: I don't get the `print ????` part.

Comment: You have a variable whose name is determined at runtime and it is in the binding. But there could be a lot of stuff in the binding. How do you know which is the variable you want to print? Or i got everything wrong...

Comment: ??? means I miss the construct. I thought I need something like "${${m}}, but this is not allowed. I know 'm', m is poiting in binding to n, n to p

Comment: i am not sure, where this is going, but e.g. in `groovysh` you can access the context via `this`.  so this works in `groovysh`: `m='n'; n='p'; "${this."$m"}"`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
// Java code...

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("m", "n");
binding.setVariable("n", "result");

// here the script is hardcoded in this Java source
// file but could be read from anywhere...
String groovyScript = "evaluate \"println(${m})\"";

GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);

// this will println "result"
shell.evaluate(groovyScript);
```

I hope that helps.